# Getting a Lua Script Error called: Unknown Lua Script Error

Tags: lua, nlua

My Lua script works fine for me, but some people are having issues with it.

They keep getting this error:

```
NLua.Exceptions.LuaScriptException: Unknown Lua Error
```

Looking at my script it's this part right here that gives the error:

```
while true do
newfile = io.open("commands.txt")
for line in io.lines("commands.txt") do
    ccommands = newfile:read "*a"
end
newfile:close()
```

Some people have fixed this by moving the script and the software that's running the Lua Script to their C: Drive. Others are still having the issue, even running as administrator, but I was told it could be possible because of their system language is not in English.

would anyone know why it's causing this? Like I said it runs fine for me. (using Windows 10)

Comment: thanks Joseph, didn't realize there was an NLua language

Comment: What your script should do?  Why do you open the file twice (io.open and io.lines)?  To traverse lines of the file, try `for line in io.lines("commands.txt") do ccommands = line end`